# memcached memory usage difference on 32- and 64-bit

Tags: hardware, memory, memcached

We have a bunch of boxes running memcached. Some are 32-bit and some are 64-bit, **but all run a 32-bit install of RHEL** due to various Perl-related things. We'll call them type A and B respectively. Both types run memcached 1.2.8 with the same amount of memory allocated via the `-m` switch. Every memcached instance contains the same data -- in this installation we're not using it as a distributed hash but a local store on each machine. A separate process is responsible for seeding each instance with fresh data at a regular interval.

Today we noticed all the 64-bit machines had started evicting items:

**Type A, 32-bit**

```
STAT curr_items 115208
STAT evictions 0
STAT limit_maxbytes 67108864
```

**Type B, 64-bit**

```
STAT curr_items 122192
STAT evictions 1049488
STAT limit_maxbytes 67108864
```

Initially I thought the type B machines were using more RAM but I was misunderstanding the `rusage` stats (see edit history). Any ideas why the type B machines would start evicting before the others, even with the same data seeded at the same time as the type A machines? Is it down to the underlying hardware being 64-bit? I'm displaying a shameful ignorance of computer hardware here but there's only one way to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

If both A- and B- types are on 32bit OS, there should be no difference in object sizes for userland apps like memcached. Differences could be seen for kernel if PAE is enabled/disabled, but even that should not affect userland memory usage.

Could you post full output of `stats`, `stats sizes`, `stats items` for both types? (Two last can take long for large memory, but at 67M that's not your case).

And, sure, initial output of `memcached -vv`.

Comment: We ended up having to restart them to bump the RAM up. I'll keep an eye on them and compare the slab allocations if their usage patterns start to differ. Thanks!